# Unclear hierarchical structure Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

If I geocode regions and or addresses the google maps api returns unlogical geographical results. Sometimes a city is returned as an administative area and sometimes the same city is returned as a locality. Why? I just don't get the logic.

For example, if I geocode "Neerijnen, Nederland" (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Neerijnen,Nederland) I get the following result:

- Country: Nederland
- Administrative area level 1: Gelderland
- **Administrative area level 2**: Neerijnen

If I geocode and address in the same city, google returns it as a locality. If I geocode "Van Pallandtweg 11, 4182 CA Neerijnen, Nederland" I get the following result:

- Country: Nederland
- Administrative area level 1: Gelderland
- **Locality**: Neerijnen
- Street: Van Pallandtweg
- etc.

Can someone explain the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Geocoding API is designed to resolve address string to coordinates or vice versa. In order to get better results you should provide a complete address in format supported by national postal service. When you provide string like `Neerijnen, Nederland` this is not considered as a complete street address, but the incomplete or ambiguous query. Indeed, the Neerijnen is a municipality and a town in the Netherlands, so there is administrative area and locality in the Google database with the same name. Geocoding API intended to return the best match for forward geocoding (typically only one result). In case of ambiguity like in your example Google will select a result that has a higher score (prominence) according to internal criteria. I cannot say why admin area 2 has a higher score, because I'm not from Google.

You can see the administrative area borders

https://maps.google.com/?q=Neerijnen,+Netherlands&ftid=0x47c6f414182c45d5:0xb34aa41b420fdfa4

and locality borders

https://maps.google.com/?q=4182+Neerijnen,+Netherlands&ftid=0x47c6f4192fae3201:0x9c3d72f48c595a87

There is an article regarding best practices in Geocoding API that covers also the case of incomplete and ambiguous queries:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

I hope this helps!

Comment: What I would have expected in this case was an answer like:
Country: Nederland
Administrative area level 1: Gelderland
Administrative area level 2: Neerijnen
Locality: Neerijnen
Street: Van Pallandtweg
etc.